# Prevent test migrations from being run on a specific database

Tags: django, cockroachdb

I have a Django application connectinig to 2 database.
Both of them as seen by Django as PostgreSQL database but one of them is not a PostgreSQL (but uses the PostgreSQL binary protocol so it uses the same driver (CockroachDB).

Currently it looks like during test runs, Django try to run the migration on both databases.

How can I avoid that ? I still need the database to be accessible during the tests, but no to run the migration (As it's not compatible for now and the migrations are run outside from Django)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',

         ...
    },
    'livedb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If it uses the postgres driver but lives in a different place, can you not just set the host, user & password differently?

Comment: They are different already, but Django is trying to run the migrations for testing 
 on both databases which won't work on this case (As CockroachDB doesn't support the same level of SQL than PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) that prevents migration. Assuming `livedb` is the DB you do not want to migrate, it would look like this:

```
class LiveDBRouter:

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Do not allow migrations on livedb.
        """
        return db != 'livedb'
```

Then you configure that router:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.LiveDBRouter']
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that but looks like this setting is ignored when running tests ? It keep trying to create the database even after defining it and setting DATABASE_ROUTERS